# Mocking methods with jest and vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, babel-jest

I have been trying to test if a method is called in a Vue component when a specific button is triggered.

I've been successfull using this method at first:

```
it('should call the methodName when button is triggered', () => {
  const methodNameSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'methodName')

  wrapper.find('.is-success').trigger('click')

  expect(methodNameSpy).toBeCalled()
})
```

So this worked just fine for some components, but I still get an error telling me that it did not get called on some other components

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I have one idea on why this simple test is failling in this case, but i have no idea on how to fix it or even if it is the reason.

This component is a "tooltip", once the save / close button is pressed, it closes, and disapears. Maybe that's why the test is failing, because it can't find the tested elements anymore.

Here is the component and the tests

component.vue

```html
<template lang="html">
    <div class="editresewin" @click.stop>
        <div class="topbar">
            <button
                class="button is-danger"
                @click="close"
            >
                <b-icon icon="close" />
            </button>
            <button
                class="button is-success"
                @click="save"
            />
            <h2 class="...">Title</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="...">
            <div class="...">
                <label>Label</label>
                <input .../>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

component.spec.vue

```
describe('TheEditResourceFile', () => {
  let wrapper
  let defaultParams

  beforeEach(() => {
    defaultParams = {
      localVue,
      i18n,
      router,
      store,
      propsData: {
        args: {
          title: '',
          description: '',
        },
        type: 'file',
      },
    }
    wrapper = shallowMount(TheEditResourceFile, defaultParams)
  })

  it('should trigger the save method', () => {
      const saveSpy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'save')

      wrapper.find('.is-success').trigger('click')

      expect(saveSpy ).toBeCalled()
    })
})
```

Let me know if more clafication is needed.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Wrong code on failed test.

Comment: The unit is the `component` so you don't have to test its implementation.
If the method called emit an event for example it's better to test that when you click on the button, the correct event is emitted.

Comment: @AdriHM I see what you mean, unfortunatly the methods does not emit event in this case, but i'll keep in mind that for some other tests I have to make, thank you :)

Comment: yes the event emission was an example. What does the method do ?

Comment: It send a dispatch to patch a specific object.
The dispatch it self is tested somewhere else.

Comment: you have to mock the store and also the dispatch function and test that the dispatch has been called with correct parameters

Answer (score 0):

1. In Vue 2, the mock/spy on the component method must be done on the component's `.methods` definition -- not the wrapper -- **before** mounting. (As of Vue 3.2.31, this order is no longer required for methods called post-mount.)
2. The `trigger('click')` call needs to be `await`ed because it invokes the bound method asynchronously.
3. The spy is always truthy, so `toBeTruthy()` is a meaningless assertion. Instead, assert [`toHaveBeenCalled()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalled) on the spy.

```js
it('should trigger the save method', () => {
  1️⃣
  const saveSpy = jest.spyOn(TheEditResourceFile.methods, 'save')
  wrapper = shallowMount(TheEditResourceFile, defaultParams)

  2️⃣
  await wrapper.find('.is-success').trigger('click')

  3️⃣
  expect(saveSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for the third point, it's my bad, I was trying something and forgot to put the test back how it was before. I'll edit this right away.

So i tried this before but got this error :
`Property 'methods' does not exist on type 'VueConstructor<Vue>'.`

Also tried `setMethod` but I also get a deprecated error, the test was sucessfull tho.